# How can I change icon.filename of buildozer?

Tags: kivy, icons, filenames, buildozer

I use buildozer with kivy (python), and I'd like to change the icon. In buildozer.spec I found `#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png`. I tried to uncomment this, but it is still not working.

Which path do I have to write? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place the image file into the directory that you have the code of your app,
delete the #
and Write:
icon.filename = NameOfTheYourImage.png